# Taking screenshot in Java (Robot, code working but not with external full screen application)

Tags: java, awt, fullscreen, screenshot, awtrobot

I am using the following code for taking a screenshot:

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
        ImageIO.write(image,"png", file);
```

This code is running good. It takes screen shots of my desktop when I run the program, etc.

However, when I try to run first some game, application in **full screen**, it doesn't work properly. It renders either black screen, either the same "initial" picture.

Is this problem known, and how to fix this please?

**Second question :**
Is this possible to simulate some "Print Screen" key we can have on keybord in order to solve this problem? Because I can use *Print Screen key* when the application is launched in full screen, and when I paste I got my screen. 
(Like this but in java : [Copy the contents of the screen or the active window](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18341) ? )

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT** : Andrew Thompson was kind to propose me the following code that will be a good first step to solve this problem :

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class ScreenshotUsingPrintScreen {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i = KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN;
    Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    DataFlavor[] flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
    System.out.println("Before: ");
    for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
        System.out.println(flavor);
    }

    // get the screenshot
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
    robot.delay(40);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
    robot.delay(40);

    cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
    System.out.println("After: ");
    for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
        System.out.println(flavor);
    }
}
```

}

It compiles well but however I receive the following error while then running it.

```
Before: 
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-text-encoding;representationclass=[B]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-serialized-object;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=unicode]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot open system clipboard
    at sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.openClipboard(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getClipboardFormatsOpenClose(SunClipboard.java:332)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors(SunClipboard.java:172)
    at zipprotected.threadsTest.ScreenshotUsingPrintScreen.main(ScreenshotUsingPrintScreen.java:36)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: It could be a *feature* of the game itself, that it has mechanisms to prevent coders from creating or running "bots" and thus prevent them from having an unfair advantage.

Comment: In my case not at all. Plus we can make some screenshots with PRINT SCREEN.

Comment: It appears that you're using a ScreenCapture function built in to the Robot library.  Where do you get this robot library?

Comment: @ anorton : here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: @user: you may be assuming too much. Yes it may still be a problem even with your ability to use print screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this problem known,..

Yes.  Typically it is caused by moving the rendering down to the level of the graphics card itself (largely side-stepping the OS).

> ..and how to fix this please?

AFAIU it cannot be fixed.  Even native screenshot apps. will not manage to gain a screenshot of such a rendering.

> Is this possible to simulate some "Print Screen" key in order to solve this problem?

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class ScreenshotUsingPrintScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i = KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN;
        Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        DataFlavor[] flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
        System.out.println("Before: ");
        for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
            System.out.println(flavor);
        }

        // get the screenshot
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.delay(40);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.delay(40);

        cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
        System.out.println("After: ");
        for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
            System.out.println(flavor);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Before: 
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-text-encoding;representationclass=[B]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/rtf;representationclass=java.io.InputStream]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/rtf;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/rtf;representationclass=[B]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-serialized-object;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=unicode]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=windows-1252]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
After: 
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=image/x-java-image;representationclass=java.awt.Image]
```

Comment: So why can I use Print screen key? Is there a way to use this feature inside my java code please? Also, When I do not run the application in full screen, my program runs properly.

Comment: But don't forget to release the key too!

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson : Thanks! I am now trying to combine it with a bufferedImage, in my case making "image=robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);" does not work. @ HoverCraft Full Of Eels: what do you mean by releasing ?

Comment: *facepalms* --- He means that, just like with physical interaction, a key that logically goes down has to come back up as well; Otherwise you have a stuck key. --- @user1638875 And `image = robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);` will not work because it itself serves no data-related purpose; The result does not come from the method itself, but from it's consequences on the environment. In short, your screenshot is not returned by the method, but saved on clipboard memory, from where you should retrieve it by other means.

Comment: I found on the internet the method getClipboard() but it seems to be really old, and doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was wondering, is there a way to save this dataflavor as png file for example ?

Comment: Promise I will but for now I got an error : java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
sept. 04, 2012 1:45:36 PM pack.main go
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The error given in a separated class : "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot open system clipboard
 at sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.openClipboard(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getClipboardFormatsOpenClose(SunClipboard.java:332)
 at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors(SunClipboard.java:172)"

Comment: I cannot (do not even try to) read code or exception output in comments.  Edit it into the question using code formatting, and notify me.

Comment: Question updated. I must say thank you so much for trying to help me like that.

Comment: @ user : cb has to be set to NULL first, so that it clears everything linked with the clipboard that may be used by Windows. Normally should works after that.

Comment: Thanks!!It works now! I accepted your answer for this question, and asked another one to save dataflavor as png file here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264146/how-to-save-datafloor-into-as-image-png-file-in-java, as Andrew Thompson suggested me. I feel that I am close to the final work :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is right in front of you, try thinking differently. You don't need to use `PrtScr` function because almost all platforms (games) have an inbuilt screenshot function.

In Steam for example, this includes all games played through steam, <kbd>F12</kbd> is used to take a screentshot. Instead of using `PrtScr`, use <kbd>F12</kbd> in your code, the file is automatically stored, use that file, do what ever you like with it.

I know this is a bit late, but I hope it helps you with your project.

Edit to add exact code:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_0) {
    Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
    } 
    catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication6.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This is in relation to steam, basically when you press "0", your program will simulate the input of <kbd>F12</kbd>, this will take a screenshot, which will be stored in `"STEAM\userdata\137637106\760\remote\570\screenshots"` directory.

Hope this helps.