# Simulate Print Screen under Windows

Tags: java, netbeans, bufferedimage, awtrobot, printscreen

I know we can simulate the print screen with the following code:

```
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
```

..but then how to return some `BufferedImage`?

I found on Google some method called `getClipboard()` but Netbeans return me some error on this one (cannot find symbol).

I am sorry to ask this, but could someone show me a working code on how returning from this key press a `BufferedImage` that I could then save?

Comment: You might need to release that key before it will save the `Image` to the clipboard, but I'm not sure.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251447/418556) on your earlier question.  And stop SHOUTING at us..

Answer (score 8):

This won't necessarily give you a `BufferedImage`, but it will be an `Image`. This utilizes [`Toolkit.getSystemClipboard`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getSystemClipboard%28%29).

```
final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
if (clipboard.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)) {
  final Image screenshot = (Image) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
  ...
}
```

If you *really* need a `BufferedImage`, try as follows...

```
final GraphicsConfiguration config
    = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
          .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
final BufferedImage copy = config.createCompatibleImage(
    screenshot.getWidth(null), screenshot.getHeight(null));
final Object monitor = new Object();
final ImageObserver observer = new ImageObserver() {

  public void imageUpdate(final Image img, final int flags,
      final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
    if ((flags & ALLBITS) == ALLBITS) {
      synchronized (monitor) {
        monitor.notifyAll();
      }
    }
  }
};
if (!copy.getGraphics().drawImage(screenshot, 0, 0, observer)) {
  synchronized (monitor) {
    try {
      monitor.wait();
    } catch (final InterruptedException ex) { }
  }
}
```

Though, I'd really have to ask why you don't just use [`Robot.createScreenCapture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

```
final Robot robot = new Robot();
final GraphicsConfiguration config
    = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
          .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
final BufferedImage screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(config.getBounds());
```

Comment: *"I'd really have to ask.."*  Good question.  Apparently the OP presumes we all sit around, obsessing on their questions alone.  A previous question explained that `createScreenCapture` produces a black image for some full-screen apps.  Also a good answer.  +1

Comment: First of all, thank you for your anser. Secondy, I don't really know why but when I run your code I receive the following error: "SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: I think it comes from my following code : "ImageIO.write(copy,"png", file1);   ", is that right ?

Comment: @user1638875 I don't know, I didn't write that code. The name of the exception is not enough information for me to help... perhaps if you had a full trace.