# How to save DataFlavor[] as an image file in java?

Tags: java, save, image

Considering the code :

```
    Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    DataFlavor[] flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
    flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
    for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
        System.out.println(flavor);
    }
    BufferedImage buff = //  flavors  <- I don't know what to put here to make it working; 
    File file = new File("newimage.png");
    ImageIO.write(buff,"png", file);
```

Which returns :

```
 java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=image/x-java-image;representationclass=java.awt.Image]
```

**How to set the BufferedImage line in order to save this as a picture**, (let's say png file)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class SaveClipboardScreenshot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // get the screenshot
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.delay(40);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
        robot.delay(404);

        Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        DataFlavor[] flavors = cb.getAvailableDataFlavors();
        System.out.println("After: ");
        for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
            System.out.println(flavor);
            if (flavor.toString().indexOf("java.awt.Image")>0) {
                Object o = cb.getData(flavor);
                Image i = (Image)o;
                // ImageIO will not write an Image
                // It will write a BufferedImage (a type of RenderedImage)
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        i.getWidth(null),
                        i.getHeight(null),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
                g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
                g.dispose();

                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
                sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sp);
                File f = new File(
                        System.getProperty("user.home") + 
                        File.separator + 
                        "the.png");
                ImageIO.write(bi, "png", f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

> How can I use your code into a static function?

In Java they are called methods, and every `main` ***is*** static.

> Ex returning a File.

Change

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

..to something like..

```
public static File getScreenshot() throws Exception {
```

..and also change..

```
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", f);
```

..to..

```
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", f);
return f;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this will be my last Question : How can I use your code into a static fonction? Ex returning a File.

Comment: *"Thank you very much."*  Thanks is well expressed in an up-vote.  *"I think this will be my last Question"* Wish I had a dollar for every time I heard that.  ;) Given the question **has** been answered in my 1st reply, see my **last** words on *this* question, in the update above.

Comment: I just not want to be unpolite. Well, I don't know what to say because your code is working perfectly when there is nothing launched in full screen. But once I start one program in full screen, it doesn't work, the file itself is not created. No idea why. I actually use the screenshot that should be created later on, and " SEVERE: null java.io.FileNotFoundException: " when there is some program in full Screen. When no program in full screen, the file is well created and I can use it. I am lost I don't know what to do anymore. But I guess I should stop bother you about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {

    Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)cb.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
    File file = new File("newimage.png");
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);

} catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
int n=0
for (DataFlavor flavor : flavors) {
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)clipboard.getData(flavor);
File file = new File("image"+ n+".png");
ImageIO.write(image , "png", file);
n++;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I edited my post in order to make it more clear. Do you see my problem?

Comment: you dont know what to put to BufferedImage or DataFlavor?
Did you tried this line : BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)clipboard.getData(flavor); in your for loop?

Comment: I want, from a DataFlavor[], "convert it" in BufferedImage, but I don't know how to make it, as shown on the updated Question above.

Comment: but is flavors is a list and each element might be separate picture?